# No puedo enviar este contrato de usdt firmado

Tags: nodejs, solidity

**Es probado de todo estoy usando web3 quiero hacer una transferencia de usdt desde el backend enviarlos ya firmados **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. He aquí [el por qué](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976) es mala idea compartir el código como imagen. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: tienes razon disculpame